# How to handle random attacks on my home router/services

Tags: router, security, firewall

It seems that I am being constantly targeted by foreign entities for various attacks.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like my router, netgear r7800, has any "auto-ban" functionality to mitigate these ongoing attacks, and I'm not sure how else to address what appears to be a constant stream of attacks.

I have an FTP server on 192.168.100.106:22 and webserver on 192.168.100.106:80.

Thoughts on what I can do here?

Here's a recent snippet of my router logs:

```
[admin login] from source 192.168.100.18, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:06:12
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:46891 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:05:34
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:05:02
[LAN access from remote] from 61.184.247.3:54473 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:04:54
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:04:37
[LAN access from remote] from 61.184.247.12:33140 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:04:32
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:15676 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:04:31
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:04:30
[LAN access from remote] from 61.184.247.6:54990 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:04:26
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:45047 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:03:26
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:03:19
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:03:10
[DoS Attack: SYN/ACK Scan] from source: 51.38.120.216, port 49999, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:03:07
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:02:59
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:02:47
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:02:31
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:12252 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:02:18
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:02:00
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:42071 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:01:13
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:01:05
[DHCP IP: 192.168.100.9] to MAC address 77:77:77:77:77:44, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:32
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:27
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:24
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:17
[DHCP IP: 192.168.100.106] to MAC address 66:66:66:66:66:33, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:15
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:12461 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:09
[LAN access from remote] from 37.49.231.58:49127 to 192.168.100.106:80, Monday, November 05, 2018 13:00:07
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 12:59:40
[LAN access from remote] from 116.31.116.21:38325 to 192.168.100.106:22, Monday, November 05, 2018 12:59:07
[DoS Attack: ARP Attack] from source: 173.92.144.1, Monday, November 05, 2018 12:59:06
```

Comment: Um, I think your router is confusing standard ARP traffic from your own ISP's default gateway as attacks?

Comment: @grawity - perhaps.  Networking is not my forte, so I dunno how to determine if there is a real issue or not.  thoughts on how to better diagnose?